# Problem with making a new folder in Ubuntu

Tags: mount, 17.04, ntfs, drive, ntfs-3g

I have a problem with making a new folder in one of my drives.
I have Ubuntu 17 and the drive format is NTFS.

I already mounted it, but I still can't make a new folder.

Result of `for i in $(lsblk -l -f|grep -i ntfs|cut -d ' ' -f 1) /etc/mtab;do grep "/dev/$i" /etc/mtab;done ;`:

```
/dev/sda2 /media/mo/0A9392143BD31443 fuseblk ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0 
/dev/sdb1 /media/mo/My\040Passport fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

Comment: You'll have to give details of what you tried and the response.  What is the exact error?

Comment: Maybe the partition is mounted read-only. Please edit your original question to add the output of the following long command line, which should show if and how the drive is mounted, **`for i in $(lsblk -l -f|grep -i ntfs|cut -d ' ' -f 1) /etc/mtab;do grep "/dev/$i" /etc/mtab;done`** ; Indent each line 4 spaces to render the output as 'code'. (You can copy and paste the command line as well as its output to avoid typing errors.)

Comment: @sudodus /dev/sda2 /media/mo/0A9392143BD31443 fuseblk ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /media/mo/My\040Passport fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0

Answer (score 0):

Two partitions with NTFS file systems were found:

```
$ for i in $(lsblk -l -f|grep -i ntfs|cut -d ' ' -f 1) /etc/mtab;do grep "/dev/$i" /etc/mtab;done
/dev/sda2 /media/mo/0A9392143BD31443 fuseblk ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /media/mo/My\040Passport fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

- `/dev/sda2` is mounted read-only `ro`
- `/dev/sdb1` is mounted read-write `rw`

I think `default_permissions,allow_other` should make it possible to write files and create a directory when mounted read-write.

You cannot write anything (and not create a directory) when a Microsoft partition is mounted read-only.

Try to check permissions with the following commands

```
ls -ld /media/mo/0A9392143BD31443
ls -ld /media/mo/'My Passport'
```

See [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072) with detailed instructions how to mount an NTFS or FAT32 partition to make it useful.

---

If Windows is hibernated or semi-hibernated (alias Fast Startup), the Windows file system(s) are not ready for writing by Linux, so Linux (and Ubuntu is Linux) does not want to mount it with write permissions.

What about your partition `/dev/sda2`? Please check, and if necessary, turn off Fast Startup in Windows and try again.